# SHA 1 hash_hmac wrong

Tags: php, sha1

I have a big problem with hash_hmac

function

```
function hmac($key, $data){
    $blocksize = 64;
    $hashfunc = 'sha1';
    if (strlen($key) > $blocksize)
        $key = pack('H*', $hashfunc($key));
    $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
    $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
    $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
    $hmac = pack('H*', $hashfunc(($key ^ $opad) . pack('H*', $hashfunc(($key ^ $ipad) . $data))));
    return bin2hex($hmac);
}
```

example is:

```
<?php
echo hmac('111111', '222222');//=1558ab6c5ab2b0d1cd129b9ad11527cf33486705
```

but my

```
$jeden = 111111;
$dwa =222222;   
$hashWiadomosci = hash_hmac('sha1', $jeden, $dwa);
```

is: 22f91d281349bb3081d3cec9f906572eec5c55b2

how i do wrong?

Comment: `hmac()` what's that function?

Comment: function hmac($key, $data){
 $blocksize = 64;
 $hashfunc = 'sha1';
 if (strlen($key) > $blocksize)
  $key = pack('H*', $hashfunc($key));
 $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
 $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
 $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
 $hmac = pack('H*', $hashfunc(($key ^ $opad) . pack('H*', $hashfunc(($key ^ $ipad) . $data))));
 return bin2hex($hmac);
}

Comment: you need to edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42875689/edit and not drop code in comments, thanks.

Comment: and I got back the same results as per what you posted. Post what the expected results are to be

Comment: Okey I edit and add function. You have this: 1558ab6c5ab2b0d1cd129b9ad11527cf33486705?

Comment: can you tell me where you got that function from? I'm getting the same results. What results are you expecting to get back, since I don't know what you are asking, sorry. Edit: from here? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Comment: The example you got that from http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php  notes: *"If you want raw or base64 output instead of hexadecimal, just change the last return line."* - that's probably why you're getting different/unexpected results.

Comment: My fault. It work.Thanks

Comment: welcome; so what would you like to do with the question? was this your fault or did I say something in comments that solved the question?

Comment: You should mark Tom's answer below as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have your input variables in the wrong order. If you look at the example from [the comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php#39492) you got this from; you can see that it is `hmacsha1($key, $data)` and not `hmacsha1($data, $key)` like you are using it and how `hash_hmac($algorithm, $data, $key)` works.

```
echo hash_hmac('sha1', '111111', '222222'); // 22f91d2813...
echo hmacsha1('111111', '222222');          // 1558ab6c5a...

echo hash_hmac('sha1', '111111', '222222'); // 22f91d2813...
echo hmacsha1('222222', '111111');          // 22f91d2813...
```

Comment: they're using 2 separate methods

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean? I copied the code from the question... You can check my code [here](https://tomudding.nl/tests/test9.php).